# How to override standard Account layout by manage package?

Tags: managed-package, page-layout, app

I have created one visualforce page using standard Account controller and i am going to prepare one package including standard Account layout & the visualforce page that i have created.

**Now, my question is :** Is it possible to add our custom visualforce page in section of account layout automatically in others org ? for example, I have given my package URL to someone else to install this package in his/her org and he/she does not not need to modify account layout and at the time of installation my Account layout should be override to their org.

This is just a scenario that i am thinking about, not a requirement. If anybody have any comment on this then please do let me know...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely create Account page layout and add your VF page as a section in that page layout.

But, after installing the package in the orgs, you need to assign the newly created page layout(your custom layout page) using Page Layout Assignment. It will not be automatically assigned.